Is there a way to streamline naming hundreds of cells?
I have two sheets "Opponent 1" and "Opponent 2", with hundreds of cells that need to be renamed. All the cells will stay the same except for one aspect, an identifying character.
Each cell should have its original name + "OP1_" or "OP2_", depending on which sheet it is in.
Example:

A1 changes to OP1_A1
A2 changes to OP1_A2

I have tried multiple things:

Creating macros

Some with keyboard shortcuts.
Sub NameChange()
'
' NameChange Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+n
'
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="OP1_", RefersToR1C1:="='Opponent 1'!R1C1"
End Sub


Some that I copy/past the recorded macro and change the name
<sub>    
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="OP1_A1", RefersToR1C1:="='Opponent 1'!R1C1"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="OP1_A2", RefersToR1C1:="='Opponent 1'!R1C1"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="OP1_A3", RefersToR1C1:="='Opponent 1'!R1C1"
</sub>


As well as just going through each individual cell to change the name




I keep seeing if/then, for loop, and iteration suggestions, but I don't know anything about coding.
All I know is pseudo-code,
For example:
        If Cell location is in sheet "Opponent 1",
            Then add "OP1_" to beginning of Cell name
        If Cell location is in sheet "Opponent 2",
            Then add "OP2_" to beginning of Cell name

This is the only thing I can think of to handle what I am trying to do. But again, it is just pseudo-code.

What if you try something like cell.Name = "OPP1_" & cell.Address(False, False)

I'm assuming the ranges on the two worksheets might be different.
ThisWorkbook is a reference to the workbook containing the code while ActiveWorkbook in your code is a reference to whichever workbook is currently active.
The code is added to a normal module (select Insert > Module).
Sub NameChange()

    With ThisWorkbook

        Dim OP1 As Range
        Set OP1 = .Worksheets("Opponent 1").Range("A1:D10") 'Update to the correct range.
        
        Dim OP2 As Range
        Set OP2 = .Worksheets("Opponent 2").Range("A1:C5") 'Update to the correct range.
        
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In OP1
            ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "OP1_" & Cell.Address(False, False), RefersTo:=Cell
        Next Cell
        
        For Each Cell In OP2
            ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "OP2_" & Cell.Address(False, False), RefersTo:=Cell
        Next Cell
    
    End With

End Sub


This... this is insanely streamlined.

Thank you, this is a lot better than what I had. Now, should I add debug.Print and error handling as i start adding more sheets and larger ranges?

No need for any Debug.Print that I can see.  Error handling is always useful - I usually use a Select Case in the error handler so can react to different errors before resuming or exiting the code.  Depending how many extra sheets you mean to add might mean taking a different approach completely (using a For Each loop to look at each sheet), same with the ranges.

Please, try the next more compact version:
Sub NameCellsTwoSheets()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
 Const nrRow As Long = 5 'the last row number where the namming must be done
 
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Opponent 1", "Opponent 2"))
    For i = 1 To nrRow
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Opponent 1"
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Name = "OP1_" & ws.Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0)
            Case "Opponent 2"
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Name = "OP2_" & ws.Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0)
            Case Else
                'do nothing...
                'for the case when you need a different naming algorithm for other sheets.
        End Select
    Next i
 Next ws
End Sub


The first thing to do with any code/algorithm is to break things down into small blocks; your pseudo-code will help with this.  However, the next step is to find appropriate instructions in your programming language to express those blocks as real code.
In your case, the main things I would recommend you need to know are variable declaration, the If statement, the For Each statement (a variant of the For statement), (for scalability purposes) the Select Case statement (also referred to as a "Switch Statement"), and the Range.Address property
The first of these means that we don't need to determine everything at once.  You can store your Prefix as a variable, to use later:
'This is still pseudo-code
Dim str_Prefix As String
If Cell location is in sheet "Opponent 1",
    Then str_Prefix = "OP1_"
If Cell location is in sheet "Opponent 2", 
    Then str_Prefix = "OP2_"

Updating that further with the correct syntax for the If statement gives:
'This is still pseudo-code
Dim str_Prefix As String
If Cell location is in sheet "Opponent 1" Then
    str_Prefix = "OP1_"
ElseIf Cell location is in sheet "Opponent 2" Then
    str_Prefix = "OP2_"
End If

If we assume for a moment that your cell is being stored in a Range Object Variable called rng_Target, then we can turn this into 'working' code:
'This is "real" VBA code
Dim str_Prefix As String
If rng_Target.WorkSheet.Name = "Opponent 1" Then
    str_Prefix = "OP1_"
ElseIf rng_Target.WorkSheet.Name = "Opponent 2" Then
    str_Prefix = "OP2_"
End If

However, as I mentioned earlier, you can use the Select Case statement to make this more scalable (i.e. if you are going to want more Worksheets)
'This is also "real" VBA code
Dim str_Prefix As String
Select Case rng_Target.WorkSheet.Name
    Case "Opponent 1"
        str_Prefix = "OP1_"
    Case "Opponent 2"
        str_Prefix = "OP2_"
    Case Else
        str_Prefix = "" 'Optional — default result if none of the other values match
End Select

You can then combine the Prefix with the A1-notation address.  (Your existing code is using R1C1-notation; there are times when A1-notation is better, there are times when R1C1-notation is better, and there are times when they are equal.)
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=str_Prefix & rng_Target.Address(False, False, xlA1, False), _
    RefersTo:="=" & rng_Target.Address(True, True, xlA1, True)

If you want expand this into a loop, you can use the special Selection keyword, for the entire range of cells that you have selected:
Dim rng_Target As Range, str_Prefix As String
For Each rng_Target In Selection.Cells
    Select Case rng_Target.WorkSheet.Name
        Case "Opponent 1"
            str_Prefix = "OP1_"
        Case "Opponent 2"
            str_Prefix = "OP2_"
        Case Else
            str_Prefix = "" 'Default Value
    End Select

    If str_Prefix <> "" Then 'Don't add a Named Range unless we have a Prefix
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=str_Prefix & rng_Target.Address(False, False, xlA1, False), _
            RefersTo:="=" & rng_Target.Address(True, True, xlA1, True)
    End If
Next rng_Target


However, as a general rule, I try to avoid using Select or ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet/ActiveCell unless it is specifically necessary — it often leads to 'unexpected' behaviour if you have the wrong thing selected.  So, using the extra functionality that the Application.InputBox method has over the regular InputBox function, we can expand this to a General Form:
Public Sub AddNamesFromRange()
    Dim rng_Selection As Range
    Set rng_Selection = Application.InputBox("Select a Range to add Names for:", Type:=8)
    
    If Not (rng_Selection Is Nothing) Then
        Dim rng_Target As Range, str_Prefix As String
        For Each rng_Target In rng_Selection.Cells
            Select Case rng_Target.Worksheet.Name
                Case "Opponent 1"
                    str_Prefix = "OP1_"
                Case "Opponent 2"
                    str_Prefix = "OP2_"
                Case Else
                    str_Prefix = "" 'Default Value
            End Select
        
            If str_Prefix <> "" Then 'Don't add a Named Range unless we have a Prefix
                rng_Target.Worksheet.Parent.Names.Add Name:=str_Prefix & rng_Target.Address(False, False, xlA1, False), _
                    RefersTo:="=" & rng_Target.Address(True, True, xlA1, True)
            End If
        Next rng_Target
    End If
End Sub


I don't think you can get more streamlined than this:
Sub NameChange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Const NumOfCells As Long = 500
    Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("A1:A" & NumOfCells).Formula = "=""OP1_""&ROW()"
    Range("A1:B" & NumOfCells).CreateNames Top:=False, Left:=True, Bottom:=False, Right:=False
    Columns(1).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

